# Why does some console.log print out typeof 1 as number, but sometimes as "number" (quoted)?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, safari, typeof

This is true in the current Google Chrome v56.0 and Safari v9.1:

In the debugger console, if I type:

```
> console.log(1, typeof 1)
  1 "number"

> console.log("1", typeof 1)
  1 number
```

Why is the first one `"number"` while the second one is `number`? (that is, why is the first one quoted but the second one is not?

Comment: i think is a vedor specific problem

Comment: i have the same result with the console (as oposite i wrote first)

Comment: ok, i removed that comment

Comment: It's a weird discrepancy in their syntax highlighting... if it's a string, the first param of log will always be black, then all the following strings params will be black too. But if the first param is whatever else type, then all following string params are red, with quotes. e.g `log("1", 1, "1")` strings are black, `log(null, "1", "1")` strings are red, `log("1", null, "1")` strings are black.

Comment: The behaviour of the console is not standardised (i.e. it's implementation dependent). Why do you care about the differences? *typeof* always returns a string, whether it's represented as `"number"` or `number` in the console is not particularly important.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it takes the call of `toString` (where it's necessary) as pattern for displaying the next part as strings.

Without quotes

> ```
> console.log("1", typeof 1)
>     1 number
>
> console.log("", typeof 1)
>     1  number
>
> console.log("0", typeof 1)
>     0 number
> ```

With quotes

> ```
> console.log(1, typeof 1)
>     1 "number"
>
> console.log({}, typeof 1)
>     1 Object {} "number"
>
> console.log(false, typeof 1)
>     1 false "number"
>
> console.log(true, typeof 1)
>     1 true "number"
>
> console.log([], typeof 1)
>     1 [] "number"
>
> console.log(() => true, typeof 1)
>     1 () => true "number"
>
> console.log(/./, typeof 1)
>     1 /./ "number"
> ```

Comment: it is not meant to be quoted

Answer (score 0):

It's not just typeof, works the same with `console.log(1, "1");` & `console.log("1", "1");`.

I think it's putting the quotes there because when you're printing two different types it's distinguishing between them for you.

Answer (score 0):

If we take a look at [the console.log](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Console/log) page on MDN, it explains:

> obj1 ... objN
>   A list of JavaScript objects to output. The string representations of each of these objects **are appended together in the order listed and output.**

So in the first example, it is combining an integer (`1`) and a string (`typeof 1`). Because there is an integer, it combines both the values and then converts them to a string. So `1` now equals the string; `1`, and `typeof 1` now equals the string of the output of `typeof 1` which is `"number"`.
Thus, the resulting string is `1 "number"`.

In the second example, `1` is already a string, so it converts neither to a string, and simple concatenates them on to each other, so the result is, as expected; `1 number`.

Comment: There is no standardisation for *console*. MDN is a public wiki, and while advice there is helpful, it is not definitive and for implementation–specific topics, may not be correct for some browsers.